# Angular 6. Execute http post without waiting for return

Tags: angular

I am trying to execute a long running http-post triggered Azure function from Angular 6. I would to kick off the function but I am not interested in waiting for the function completion on the Angular side. How could I achieve "fire-and-forget" using Angular's http module?

Here is my current code:

```js
public generateDemoData$(request: GenerateDemoDataRequestModel): Observable<boolean>{
    let functionUrl = this.getFunctionUrl("GenerateDemoData");
    return this.http.post<ServiceResponseModel<boolean>>(functionUrl, request)
    .pipe(        
      map((x: ServiceResponseModel<boolean>) => x.Data),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Just call subscribe in the method and don't return anything

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a promise.

Answer (score 3):

Just call subscribe in the method and don't return anything.

```
public generateDemoData$(request: GenerateDemoDataRequestModel): void {
    let functionUrl = this.getFunctionUrl("GenerateDemoData");
    this.http.post<ServiceResponseModel<boolean>>(functionUrl, request)
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: no need for callback at all: `() => {}`. Just use `.subscribe()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return an `Observable` if no one cares about the results. You just have to subscribe with a *noop* function.

```
public generateDemoData$(request: GenerateDemoDataRequestModel) {
     let functionUrl = this.getFunctionUrl("GenerateDemoData");
     this.http.post<ServiceResponseModel<boolean>>(functionUrl, request)
         .subscribe(Function.prototype);
}
```

The above will trigger the POST and forget about it.

You might want to include a `catch()` to handle errors, and you don't need a `map()` if no one receives the response data.